# Should one not use .class.getSimpleName() for TAGs?

Tags: android, obfuscation

I've read that one should not use TAGs like

```
private static final String TAG = ThisClassName.class.getSimpleName();
```

but rather

```
private static final String TAG = "MCLSN";
```

because ProGuard will create bugs and/or not obfuscate code correctly. Are these valid reasons?

References:

http://www.drewhannay.com/2016/02/android-logcat-tag-best-practices.html
https://blog.mindorks.com/applying-proguard-in-an-android-application

Answer (score 5):

This can certainly be a problem. I'm working with code currently which uses `getSimpleName()` for TAGs and, as mentioned already, with proguard these can be obfuscated from say "FragmentA" to "a".

If these tags are used for identification, there can easily be bugs introduced in this way as there may be multiple names obfuscated to "a".

We have an extra problem in that these obfuscated TAGs are used in database ids and fields. So fixing this issue will break database behaviour for customers.

Bad stuff, best avoided early if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, it's a matter of preference, but I prefer the simple String option.

The only benefit of using the `getSimpleName()` option is because it has support for refactoring. So it's only helpful if you're changing the class's name (which should rarely happen), or if you're copy/pasting a file to use as a template.

So if you're doing that often, I could see why you would prefer the first option. It just makes it easier to not have to manually change the TAG.

I also originally used `getSimpleName()` for TAGs until recently when I had experienced a minor issue.

When using MVVM architecture, there's really only one ViewModel per View, so I've created a ViewModelFactory that creates and returns the proper ViewModel for the View. Since it's meant to be unique, I decided to use the TAG as the identifier for the ViewModel I need.

Therefore, with a simple Switch-case statement on the TAG, I should be able to get the proper ViewModel. However, you simply can't use TAG as a case expression when you use `getSimpleName()`. I received the error: `Constant Expression Required`.

So if you only plan to use your TAG for certain situations like Logcat, you're fine with just using `getSimpleName()`. But if you plan to use them as a unique class identifier for a specific group of classes, then you'll need the pure String option.